# Retrieve TimeStamp Values From FireStore C#

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Having a really hard time retrieving any TimeStamp values from my Firestore DB and displaying them. I am able to return all other values I request.

```
[FirestoreData]
class FireBaseJobs 
{
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string jobstatus { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string workcompleted { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string labour { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string materials { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string descriptionmaterials { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string starttime { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string endtime { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I am listening to any updates made.

starttime, endtime and value are all UTC timestamps.

```
void checkFirestore()
    {

        CollectionReference docRef = database.Collection("jobs");

        Query query = database.Collection("jobs").WhereNotEqualTo("jobstatus", new[] { "Allocated", "Unallocated" });

        FirestoreChangeListener listener = query.Listen(snapshot =>
        {

            foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in snapshot.Documents)
            {
                FireBaseJobs job = documentSnapshot.ConvertTo<FireBaseJobs>();


            }
        });
    }
```

Updated

```
[FirestoreProperty]
    public object starttime { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public object endtime { get; set; }
    [FirestoreProperty]
    public object value { get; set; }
```

Comment: is the value stored as a string or a firestore.Timestamp?

Comment: Stored as Timestamp in firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing starttime, endtime and value to objects in my CLASS, then converting each object to a string and then converting to date or datetime.

Answer (score 2):

If the Timestamp is a `Firestore.Timestamp`, then it is stored as a nanosecond accurate date.Time object. Firestore has this object accessible and defined as `Firebase.Firestore.Timestamp`

Reference: [Unity C# Firestore.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/struct/firebase/firestore/timestamp)

If you are dealing with a string value: you can remove the last 3 digits to make it `Date.now()` compliant